# Multi-conditional PHP mysqli DELETE query failing

Tags: php, mysqli

SOLVED - Stupid me.... Thanks to the pointers by the commenters, $mysqli->error revealed I hadn't granted DELETE privileges to the mysql user.  All is well after adding that.

---

I just can't seem to get this query going.  Connection successfully made to DB but it's failing to delete rows in the 'custom_messages' table while showing no errors in the log... Method 1:

```
<?php


// get form.html input
    $var1 = $_POST["var1"];
    $var2 = $_POST["var2"];

$mysqli = new mysqli($_SERVER['DB_HOST'], $_SERVER['DB_USER'], $_SERVER['DB_PASS'],"theDB");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf ( "Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error );
exit ();
} else {
printf ( "DB Connection Established.\n" );
if ($mysqli->query (sprintf ( "DELETE FROM custom_messages WHERE var1='%s' && var2='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string ( $var1, $var2 ) ) )) {
    printf ( "%d rows deleted.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows );
}


//close DB connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

And I've also tried method 2 with the same result, no rows deleted. It gets as far as echoing 'one'..

```
<?php


    // get form.html input
    $var1 = $_POST["var1"];
    $var2 = $_POST["var2"];

$mysqli = new mysqli($_SERVER['DB_HOST'], $_SERVER['DB_USER'], $_SERVER['DB_PASS'],"CCv2");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf ( "Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error );
exit ();
} else {
printf ( "DB Connected.\n" );

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM custom_messages WHERE var1=? AND var2=?");
echo "one\n";
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$var1, $var2);
echo "two\n";
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
printf ( "%d rows deleted.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows );


    //close DB connection
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

I'm really scratching my head here, any help will be mightily appreciated!

Comment: Check the return value from `bind_param()`; I suspect that there should be some useful information in `$mysqli->error`

Comment: You're simply assuming that your prepare call is succeeding. You need to check if `$stmt` is boolean FALSE, which would indicate a failure. If it is a boolean false, then you end up trying to do `false->bind_param()` which is not possible. false is not an object, and definitely wouldn't have a bind_param method anyways.

Comment: Ok, I understand... How would I check boolean state? is_bool($stmt)???